# Accessing the value to a key in a couple of dictionaries in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary

I am new to Swift, what I'm trying to do is access favorite drink key from both dictionaries and return the value of both
so, favorite drink will return an array of drinks like this ["prune juice", "tea, Earl Grey"]

```
let worf = [
"name": "Worf",
"rank": "lieutenant",
"information": "son of Mogh, slayer of Gowron",
"favorite drink": "prune juice",
"quote" : "Today is a good day to die."]

let picard = [
"name": "Jean-Luc Picard",
"rank": "captain",
"information": "Captain of the USS Enterprise",
"favorite drink": "tea, Earl Grey"]

let characters = [worf, picard]

func favoriteDrinksArrayForCharacters(characters:Array<Dictionary<String, String>>) -> Array<String> {

let favoriteDrinks = favoriteDrinksArrayForCharacters(characters)
//missing step?
return favoriteDrinks

}
```

if this was objective-c I would do this

```
NSArray *favoriteDrinksForCharacters = [charactersArray valueForKey:@"favorite drink"]; 
return favoriteDrinksForCharacters;
```

Comment: whats wrong with using `return characters["favorite drink"]` ?

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use the `map` function, which applies code to every element of a collection:

```
return characters.map { $0["favorite drink"]! }
```

The brackets part is a [closure](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Closures.html), which may contain arbitrarily complex code. The `!` is because the dictionary subscript may return nil.

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative you can also check contents in a swift-based dictionary:

```
for (key, value) in dictionary {
    println("Key = \(key), and Value = \(value)")
}
```

The "(key, value)" is a tuple, which is what dictionaries vend up nicely.

Answer (score 0):

I would almost have gone with @zneak's answer but it requires an implicitly unwrapped optional (dragons — or sneaky crashes — be here).

A better solution, which accounts for the fact that an arbitrary dictionary may not actually contain a given key, would be:

```
let favouriteDrinks: [String] = characters.reduce([], combine: { (result: [String], character: [String: String]) -> [String] in
    if let favouriteDrink: String = character["favorite drink"] {
        return result + [favouriteDrink]
    }
    return result
})
```